# Move store from Apache to Nginx server

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, nginx, htaccess, apache

I'm planning on moving my Magento store from one server to another. The current server is an **Apache** server and I just got notified the new webserver will be an **Nginx** server. The hosting company noted that the new server doesn't support `.htaccess` files.

Since I already have a store I am worried what I should do about my existing `.htaccess` file

Comment: Have you made any modification to you htaccess? Does your new host support Magento setups?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I haven't made any changes to the file. And yes, they do support Magento setups

Answer (score 1):

Since you new Host will support Magento and you have not made any changes to your htaccess you will not have to do anything. Keep in mind that your htaccess file is now redundant and any changes you make will not apply to your site in the future.